# Unknown coordinate type (R)

Tags: r, coordinate-system, coordinates

Have some coordinates for a spdf of the Green Mountain National Forest in Vermont in R. Downloaded from Vermont.gov website. http://geodata.vermont.gov/datasets/vt-green-mountain-national-forest-mgmt-areas-2006-polygons?geometry=-74.248%2C43.079%2C-71.347%2C43.777 
The coordinates look this:

```
 gmnf <- matrix(c(437238.82, 26905.22, 514258.28, 184930.56), nrow = 2, dimnames = list(c("x","y"),c("min","max")))
```

I thought they were in DMS and I put them in a few online calculators but the output values don't look right. They should fall within the range of Vermont but they don't. From a spdf for Vermont:

```
vt <- matrix(c(-73.43774, 42.72685, -71.46455, 45.01666), nrow = 2, dimnames = list(c("x","y"),c("min","max")))
```

Based on the metadata (linked to on the above website) these are coordinates in decimal degrees. When I change them and try to `plot(gmnf)`nothing happens. Tried with and without changing the crs but still nothing.

```
gmnf@bbox <- matrix(c(-73.454162, 42.722789, -71.465281, 45.018361), nrow = 2, dimnames = list(c("x","y"),c("min","max")))
gmnf@proj4string <- vt@proj4string
plot(gmnf)
```

What types of coordinates is gmnf in and how do I change it to decimal degrees?

Dropbox folder with the spdf for gmnf and vt:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i94ondu3cihglef/AAA6jZV2cwpersPNs_9oUP6ea?dl=0

**Update:** Solution is painfully simple. Noob

```
gmnf <- readOGR(dsn = "gmnf_shape", layer = "VT_Green_Mountain_National_Forest_Mgmt_Areas_2006__polygons")
latlong = "+init=epsg:4326"
gmnf <- spTransform(gmnf, latlong)
```

Comment: Those are likley meters but the associated coordinate system could be any number of projections. I would look at UTM and Albers first off. If the units are feet then it would be a state plane projection. Just keep in  mind that defining an arbitrary projection could get you close but still qute a bit off. I would recommend contacting the agency distributing the data and verify the correct projection.

Comment: Don't modify the slots directly that is guaranteed disaster

Answer (score 1):

Keep scrolling. That metadata clearly specifies units as metres under the spatial_data_reference subheading, although weirdly enough the bounding box is in lat/long - might be a side effect of whatever system they're using to manage the metadata...? autoupdate is nobody's friend.

Anyway the spatial reference mentions Vermont NAD83 zone 4400, and a quick google search for 'Vermont 4400 metres epsg' leads to this: https://epsg.io/102345. also, opening the shapefile in QGIS suggests EPSG:2852, which appears to be pretty much identical. How are you loading this data into R that you can't see the crs info?

Comment: (could be via maptools read)

Comment: Used rgdal:readOGR. I can access the crs info `gmnf@proj4string
CRS arguments:
 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-72.5 +k=0.999964286 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80
+towgs84=0,0,0 ` but I'm not 100% on how to interpret it. Newcomer to GIS and crs info makes no sense to me.

Comment: I think I'm still not clear on what I do with the info you've given. Changing the crs does nothing because the coordinates stay the same. I'm not sure exactly what I should be searching (what questions to ask) to fix this. I guess I'm also asking for the technicals in R.

Comment: did you use spTransform() to change the crs?